# What exactly does this compiler error want me to perform?

Tags: c++, vector

Thank you in advance for reading ! So this is the code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

std::vector<int> MonkeyCount(int n);

int main() {

    MonkeyCount(4);

    return  0;


}


std::vector<int> MonkeyCount(int n) {
    std::vector<int> MonkeyCountV;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

        MonkeyCountV.push_back(i);
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= MonkeyCountV.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << MonkeyCount.at(i) << " ";
    }
    return MonkeyCountV;
}
```

and the error is on line 23 : error C2227:  left of '->at' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
Now i red something about this, but i use this from an example i found on the internet on how to print a vector, and in that exaple, in works. The exaple is this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print(std::vector<int> const& input);

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> input = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    print(input);

    return 0;
}
void print(std::vector<int> const& input)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << input.at(i) << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Pop quiz: what is the difference between "`MonkeyCount`" and "`MonkeyCountV`". If you figure it out, you will figure out the reason for the compilation error on the line in question.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Thank you very much!

Comment: In addition to having meaningful names, it is advisable to have easily-distinguishable names. When two identifiers share 11 letters and differ in only 1, it is easy to mistake one for the other...

Comment: *What exactly does this compiler error want me to perform?* A Tango. Dance for me, human! DANCE!

Comment: @JaMiT Yes, that it's true. I will remember this next time.

Comment: @user4581301 It's just it wouldn't let me post under "Why do i get this error?" and i just tried to rephrase it.

Comment: Understood. I couldn't pass up the opportunity for a wisecrack. It's a failing and it's cost me in the past. What you should do in a case like this is put the error message's description into the title  to make it easier to find for future askers with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::cout << MonkeyCount.at(i) << " ";
```

Should be:

```
std::cout << MonkeyCountV.at(i) << " ";
```

The way you have it is trying to do ".at(i)" on the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your vector is MonkeyCountV but in the cout statement you are using MonkeyCount which is actually the name of your function. Make sure you have your variables name typed correctly.

Comment: Ohh sorry, at the time of answering there were no answers. We must have answered at almost the same time. I am sorry for any inconvenience caused because of that.

Comment: Actually, it is **me** that should be sorry - I read the times of your answers incorrectly: 'simultaneous' answers are quite common here on SO, and are fully allowed!

Comment: It's okay. You are just doing your job of keeping the community clean. No need to say sorry.